# I am creating a search function in django but it isn't working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to create a function to search for objects in base.html from the database using a keyword and printing the results in listing.html

base.html

```html
 <form method="post" action="{% url 'listing'}"  name="searchform">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="custom-form">
                            <label>Keywords </label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Property Keywords" name="search_keyword" value=""/>
                            <label >Categories</label>
                            <select data-placeholder="Categories" name = "home_type" class="chosen-select on-radius no-search-select" >
                                <option>All Categories</option>
                                <option>Single-family</option>
                                <option>Semi-detached</option>
                                <option>Apartment</option>
                                <option>Townhomes</option>
                                <option>Multi-family</option>
                                <option>Mobile/Manufactured</option>
                                <option>Condo</option>
                            </select>
                            <label style="margin-top:10px;" >Price Range</label>
                            <div class="price-rage-item fl-wrap">
                                <input type="text" class="price-range" data-min="10000" data-max="100000000000"  name="price-range1"  data-step="1" value="1" data-prefix="$₦">
                            </div>
                            <button onclick="location.href='listing'" type="button"  class="btn float-btn color-bg"><i class="fal fa-search"></i> Search</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

views.py

```py
def listing(request):
    global search_keyword
        

    p = Paginator(Property.objects.order_by('-listed_on'), 2)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    propertys = p.get_page(page)
    nums = "p" * propertys.paginator.num_pages

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'searchform' in request.POST : 
        search_keyword = request.POST['search_keyword']
        propertys = Property.objects.filter(name__contains=search_keyword)

        return render(request, 'listing.html',{'nums':nums, 'search_keyword':search_keyword, 'propertys':propertys})

    return render(request, 'listing.html',{'nums':nums,'propertys':propertys})
```

Comment: you are trying to create search `form`, not `function`, also provide the error you are facing

Comment: You options should have values.

Comment: @oruchkin I am not getting the search results

Comment: @Elyasomer i am not using those values yet

Comment: Try removing the default value for your search_keyword input. Try printing the input that comes from GET method if it's working then the problem is in function not the form

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax of [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url)<sup>[django-doc]</sup> tag is wrong, it must be `{% url 'listing' %}` not <s>`{% url 'listing'}`</s>, you forget to add `%` at the end which is not the syntax of django template language.

Try this:

Template file:

```html
 <form method="POST" action="{% url 'listing' %}"  name="searchform">
```

You can also make use of `__icontains` for case-insensitive.